# Koa server crashing when returning too many data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, koa

I developed a light node web server with Koa. I contain three services that retrieve data from a mongo database, then return them to the client.

The object returned is an array of JSON objects. It can contain until about 750.000 objects.
One object looks like the following :

`{"_id":"58a4779b783dbfa853a93e09","attributes":[{"key":"nb_mots","value":"16"},{"key":"fonction","value":"président"},{"key":"groupe_acronyme","value":"UMP"}],"datatype":"deputes","date":"2007-10-23T00:00:00.000Z","eventtype":"loi","actor":"Bernard Accoyer"}`

My server runs under Linux (Debian, I guess...).

My problem is: when I want to retrieve the whole dataset (so the 750.000 objects - using the "allevents" service as given below), my server fails. The only message I get is "Killed". I survey the state of the server by using command "top". Of course, the %CPU goes high (between 90 & 95), so do for the %MEM, but nothing critical (moreover that does the same if I try to retrieve less data).

Any idea to fix that?

Code of my server :

```
var kr = require('koa-route');
var koa = require('koa');
var app = koa();
var _ = require('lodash');

var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

var someeventsPromise = function(datatype, number){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost/eventdata", function(error, db) {
        if (error){ 
           return reject(error);
        }
        console.log("Connecté à la base de données");

        db.collection('events').find({'datatype' : datatype},{"limit": number ? number : 1000}).toArray(function(err, array)
        {
            console.log('returning %d objects', array.length);
            db.close();
            return resolve({eventsArray : array});
        });
    });
  });
}
var someevents = function * (datatype, number)
{
    var event = yield someeventsPromise(datatype, parseInt(number));
    this.body = event;
}

var alleventsPromise = function(datatype){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost/eventdata", function(error, db) {
        if (error){ 
           return reject(error);
        }
        console.log("Connecté à la base de données");

        db.collection('events').find({'datatype' : datatype}).toArray(function(err, array)
        {
            console.log('returning %d objects', array.length);
            db.close();
            return resolve({eventsArray : array});
        });
    });
  });
}
var allevents = function * (datatype)
{
    var event = yield alleventsPromise(datatype);
    this.body = event;
}

var minmaxdatesPromise = function (datatype)
{
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost/eventdata", function(error, db) {
        if (error){ 
           return reject(error);
        }
        console.log("Connecté à la base de données");

        db.collection('events').find({'datatype' : datatype}, {date : 1}).toArray(function(err, array)
        {
            console.log('returning %d objects', array.length);
            db.close();

            let g = _.map(_.uniqBy(array, function(d) {return d.date}), function(d) { return new Date(d.date);});
            console.log('mapping to %d objects', g.length);

            g.sort(function(a,b) { return b - a ; });

            let minmax = { maxdate : g[0], mindate : g[g.length - 1]};
            return resolve(minmax);
        });
    });
  });
}

var minmaxdates = function * (datatype)
{
    var dates = yield minmaxdatesPromise(datatype)
    this.body = dates;
}


app.use(kr.get('/someevents/:datatype/:number', someevents));
app.use(kr.get('/allevents/:datatype', allevents));
app.use(kr.get('/minmaxdates/:datatype', minmaxdates));

app.listen(3010);
```

Comment: Maybe don't do it!?

Comment: My guess, you run out of memory and your computer kills the process. Try reducing the number of records to like 10 and check if everything is right with your code then try and figure out how to consume less memory although I think you can't because the amount of records are too many.

Comment: totally right : it doesn't fail when I reduce the number of data, but sometimes I need to get them all. I was suggested to use stream and pipe.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm pretty sure that my issue is related to the fact that I have to many data to retrieve, I tried to send them through a stream (instead of storing them in a big array).

No luck, I have another issue then :

> Error: write EPIPE
>        at exports._errnoException (util.js:1023:11)
>        at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:804:14)

My code is the following :

```
var kr = require('koa-route');
var koa = require('koa');
var app = koa();
var _ = require('lodash');

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;


var allevents = function * (datatype)
{

  var ctx = this;

  var db = yield MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/eventdata');
  console.log("Querying all data for " + datatype);

  // Get the collection
  var col = db.collection('events');

  ctx.body = col.find({'datatype' : datatype}).stream(
  { 
      transform: function(doc) { 
        return JSON.stringify(doc);
      }
  });
}

app.use(kr.get('/allevents/:datatype', allevents));

app.listen(3010);
```

Last things : all results are used in a C# Unity script (just in case).

Thanks in advance.

BTW: I can't retrieve less data, I need all of them.